# Access Denied using CreateFile from Windows API

Tags: c#, file, winapi

Recently I've run in to the issue with MAX_PATH  in the File/Directory library in .Net, so I started looking into alternatives.

I'm attempting to rebuild files from raw data stored in a database and have had no issues doing so so far using `new FileStream("G:\Location\temp.txt", FileMode.Create)` etc, however I've been asked to change the structure of the rebuilt files, and thus run into the character limit.

I've attempted to use the example from [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/03/26/long-paths-in-net-part-2-of-3-long-path-workarounds-kim-hamilton.aspx?PageIndex=1#comments), like this:

```
SafeFileHandle fileHandle = CreateFile(strDirectory,
EFileAccess.GenericWrite, EFileShare.None, IntPtr.Zero,
ECreationDisposition.OpenAlways, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

int lastWin32Error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
if (fileHandle.IsInvalid)
{
    throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(lastWin32Error);
}
```

Where `strDirectory = "G:\Really\Long\Folder\Structure\Temp.txt"`

However, I'm getting an 'Access is denied' exception being thrown. I have full Read/Write permissions to the target folder, so I'm not sure what the problem could be.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Backslashes in non-verbatim string literals have to be escaped: `"G:\\Really\\Long\\Folder\\Structure\\Temp.txt"` or `@"G:\Really\Long\Folder\Structure\Temp.txt"`.

Comment: Sidestepping OS limitations seems to me like a bad solution... In which context will these written files be used? I don't think Explorer will even see them...

Comment: Is `G` a network share?

Comment: @spender Is is a network share, and they're being transferred from an old system to a new one, and they need to be put in a specific folder structure that represents the structure of the documents in the old system.

Comment: @Alex : Can't you mount a more specific location as a drive that points to a folder deeper in the hierarchy so your paths become shorter? IIRC, the command-prompt `subst` command still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must prefix the path with the string `\\?\` in order to bypass the `MAX_PATH` limitation. This is documented in the [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) MSDN information where it states:

> In the ANSI version of this function, the name is limited to MAX_PATH characters. To extend this limit to 32,767 wide characters, call the Unicode version of the function and prepend `"\\?\"` to the path. For more information, see [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).